# PowerShell Equivalent for Word ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word, ms-office, office-automation

I have a VB script within a Word doc macro that converts autonumber fields to text.  The VB script is as follows:

```
Sub ReplaceNumbers() 
    ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```

How can this be launched from within PowerShell to prevent the need to run a macro within Word?  I have tried several things and have been unable to get it to function correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [vbscript] is another tag I'd suggest here, as that seems to be where you're going with this.

Comment: @JimmySmith Read the OP's question more carefully: *"I have a VB script **within a Word doc macro**"* (emphasis mine). This is the realm of VBA, not VBScript; they too are different things, as their tag guidances indicate.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] as well as the guidance offered ohn the tags you selected

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton you can't have a VBScript within existing VBA... it'd simply be part of that code.  VBScript files would be separate entities, but I may be assuming too much and the way that is phrased is possible in a way I have not seen.  OP may have to revise the question to appease both of our hangups.

Comment: @JimmySmith The way I'm reading it, the OP is saying "VB script" in the "some script in VB" sense, rather than the literal "VBScript" interpretation. But you have a valid point that they may also not realize the difference between these two either (as might be suggested from originally tagging this as a [tag:vb.net] question), so I guess approaching this as a possible VBScript question is plausible. If only people could write their questions more clearly...

Comment: We'll get it narrowed down though lol.  Honestly, when I was a bit more of a newbie I mixed up .vbs, vba, and VB6(RIP) a lot. We're all learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a bit different as you're not actually within the context of the "ActiveDocument" so you'd have to open it via the Microsoft Word object, then run createdDocumentObject.ConvertNumbersToText.  Also, you'll want to save the following to a ".VBS" [here's an example](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_file_create.htm) to be ran when you need it.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set yourDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\YourDocumentHere.doc")

yourDoc.ConvertNumbersToText
yourDoc.Save    
objWord.Quit
```

Name this file something like "ConvertNumbersToTextInDocuments.vbs"

Ultimately, from Powershell then you'd need to execute this.

```
cscript.exe C:\ConvertNumbersToTextInDocuments.vbs
```